# Intuition behind ambiguity of direction using linear array

Tags: antenna, signal-processing, radar

I have recently started studying array signal processing. I am struggling to understand the intuition behind ambiguity of direction using a single linear array and how it is solved using two parallel linear arrays. Can anyone please explain me?

Comment: With two arrays you can use differential processing to give you more accurate results. Common mode reflections can be cancelled out, etc. Doppler effects such as motion become more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a linear array of sensors aligned in a North-South direction. This array cannot distinguish between a signal arriving from the East versus a signal arriving from the West. Either signal will arrive at all of the sensors at the same time. Now consider what happens if there are two parallel arrays designated A and B with array A to the West of array B.  A signal arriving from the East will reach the sensors in array B before the sensors in array A.  Similarly a signal arriving from the West will reach the sensors in array A before those in array B. Thus the directional ambiguity no longer exists.